# JS RegEx Find and Replace based on Group

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace, regex-group

I am trying to search for two characters: 1.`', '` and 2. a `'('`.  So if a comma and a space is found replace with just a comma and if the ( is found replace with blank.

Below is what I have and I know I could do two replace, but was looking on combining into one using groups possible... like `$1 ='' $2 = ','`?

```
str.replace(/(\()|(,\s)/g, '');
```

Comment: @wdosanjos that = damn lol.

Comment: When you need to keep one text and remove the other it is possible with capturing groups in alternations with backreferences - see another anubhava's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` function accepts a function as the second parameter. You can use that to replace any match to whatever you want. The first parameter to the function is the matched string.

See more details [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a captured group and back-reference:

```
str = str.replace(/(,) |\(/g, '$1');
```

**Code Sample:**

```js
var str = 'abc, 123( something.'
console.log(str.replace(/(,) |\(/g, '$1'))
//=> "abc,123 something."
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CVFhSy/1)

Comment: I think the expected result should be `abc,123  something` (two spaces between '123' and 'something' as per OP.

Comment: OP: "comma and a space is found replace with just a comma and if the ( is found replace with blank." So the answer is right.

Comment: @wdosanjos: But OP wrote: `if the ( is found replace with blank` which means no space for `(`

Comment: Your solution will change `abc, 123(something` to `abc,123something`, which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @wdosanjos: That should be a question to OP. as answer is as per the requirements in question.

Answer (score 0):

**Two Steps:**

*Replace ', ' to ','*

```
const regex = /(\,\s)/gm;
const str = `abc, 123( something.`;
const subst = `,`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

*Replace ')' to ''*

```
const regex = /(\()/gm;
const str = `abc, 123( something.`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

**Mixed Solution:**

```js
    regex = /(\,\s)/gm;
    str = `abc, 123( something.`;
    subst = `,`;
    
    // The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
    result = str.replace(regex, subst);
    
    regex = /(\()/gm;
    str = result;
    subst = ``;
    
    // The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
    result = str.replace(regex, subst);
    //
    console.log(result);
```

*If I help you, remember to mark me as the answer to the question*

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the `String.prototype.replace` can be string or function. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#parameters)

## Replacement function

If it's a function, it will be invoked for every match and its return value is used as the replacement text.

```js
function replacer(match, p1, p2, /* …, */ pN, offset, string, groups) {
  return replacement;
}
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement

## Replacement string

```js
console.log(
  "Your age: 50".replace(/.+?(?<age>\d+)/, "age named capure group: $<age>")
);
```

More info about what you can use in the replacement string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement